# Pipe bang when shutting faucet off

Tags: plumbing

I hear an audible bang when I shut my kitchen faucet off if there was any hot water. When the lever is positioned far right to cold only, there is no bang.

Does this mean the hot water pipe is not not adequately secured to the framing structure so it vibrates?

Comment: are the pipes accessible?   if not your best solution is to play music...

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question directly: yes, this may mean that the water pipe is not adequately secured.

However, even when the pipe is adequately secured, you can still hear a "bang" because of what's called "water hammer."

The solution to your problem is:

1. if the hot water pipe is accessible, check to see if it is properly secured
2. install [water hammer arrestors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000H5MQNM)

[Here is a good video on water hammer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbkE0HhEHVY)